# PTAM map orientation

Tags: ros, ethzasl-ptam, tum-ardrone, ptam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I'm working with a hand held camera looking down and PTAM. I would like to know what can I do to have the map obtained from PTAM orientated, because I've seen that in the demos the grid is always on the floor. I mean, how to make the axis of the camera be the same axis of the PTAM map, and the grid always in the floor or parallel.

Any information will be appreciated.
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53790/ptam-map-orientation/) by [MarcSure](https://answers.ros.org/users/4095/marcsure/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm not a ptam expert, but I will try to answer you. The ptam authors will give you better information.

1. Why do you need the grid on the same axis? You will still get localization information with respect to this axis.
2. Make sure you always have translation and no rotational camera motion when you initialize the map. This affects the map initialization.
3. The algorithm looks for change in position of the features when the map is initialized. If there are features at different heights, it means that you are not facing a averagely plain ground plane. This would naturally make the ptam to initialize the grid plane in an inclined manner.

If you find better answers or more information on the same, kindly update this post.

---

Originally posted by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) with karma: 528 on 2013-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1